# line of orthocentre

Tags: geometry

The circumcentre of a triangle lies at the origin
and its centroid is the mid point of the line segment
joining the points $(a^2 + 1, a^2 + 1)$ and $(2a, –2a)$,
a  0. Then for any $a$, the orthocentre of this
triangle lies on the line :

I got the centroid as $\left({(a+1)^2\over 2} , {(a-1)^2\over 2}\right)$

But now how to proceed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line#Distances_between_centers

Comment: In the second line should $l$ be $1$?

Comment: @user254665 yes